# Firebase Google Auth In Ionic 4 - How to check If the user is logging in for the first time so that I can navigate the user to a different page?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I have an app which you can log in with email and google auth. The user can create a account and after creating the account I navigate them to creating a profile which is displayed on the home page so... What I want to do is, since google authentication is only one button I want to check when the user signs in with google for the first time I want them to create a profile right after using google auth and then when they try to log in again with google auth I want to display the home page so that they can see their data rather then creating one more profile.

```
user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private toast:ToastController, 
    public navCtrl:NavController,
    private gplus: GooglePlus,
    private platform: Platform) {
      this.user = this.fireAuth.authState;
    }

    googleLogin() {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.nativeGoogleLogin();
      } else {
        this.webGoogleLogin();
      }
    }
    async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
      try {
        const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
          'webClientId': '****************.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          'offline': true,
          'scopes': 'profile email'
        })
        return await this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)).then(suc=>{
          this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(async auth => {
            if(!auth.uid){
              this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
            }
            else{this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/profile');
            }
          })  
        }).catch(ns =>{
          alert("error")
        })

        } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

What this `nativeGoogleLogin()` function does is that it first shows the profile creation page and after that it navigates the user to the homepage but it always repeats this so that's why I need help from you guys! I want the user to create a profile only once after that I want them to go to the homepage every single time.

Comment: did you explore what custom parameters you could pass with auth ? like https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.html#setcustomparameters just wonder what have you tried already

Comment: I've searched them but could not really made the code work properly with my lack of expirience in js&ts In general, but thank you for your suggestion!